# Do I need to file schedule C if I had a net loss?

Tags: united-states, sole-proprietorship, losses, form-1040x, schedule-c

I ran a business in 2015 (sole proprietorship) that had a net loss, and I have discontinued that business. Do I need to file a schedule C for it, assuming I do not want/need to offset other earnings by that loss (and may even benefit from a larger EIC)?

EDIT: None of my income was large enough to be reported by anyone on a 1099 or similar. All my income from this business came from individual customers (as opposed to business entities).

Comment: Did that business conduct enough activities that other business would have filed tax forms that would impact your tax situation?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you had income, then you'll need to file Schedule C this year. The fact that it won't get reported on a 1099 does not eliminate your obligation to pay tax on it.  The fact that you also had a loss does not change the fact that you had income - It may alter the amount of tax that you ultimately need to pay.